# How does Magento run if many extensions override it?

Tags: magento-2.1, overrides, xml

2 extensions are used which override `customer_account_create.xml`
Example:
Extension 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="content">
                <block class="TTV\TermCondition\Block\RegisterCondition" name="customer_form_register" template="TTV_TermCondition::register.phtml" cacheable="false">
                </block>
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```

And this is Extension 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Test\Translate\Block\Translate" name="customer_form_register" template="Test_Translate::translate.phtml" cacheable="false">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Which extension will Magento execute?

Comment: you can check its using app/etc/config.php file to check whether first module is load, Which module is called last that win the overrider file.

Comment: i try but both 2 extension is not use

Comment: onlly one extension are used which are called at last

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The second mouse gets the cheese".
The layout files are merged before being processed.
So the last extension that is loaded gets to display what it wants to display.
Normally, the last extension you see in `app/etc/config.php` is the last one loaded.
If there is a dependency between extensions, then the one that depends on the other will be loaded last.
If there is no dependency, the one you installed last will be loaded last.

Comment: the behavior is same for M1 also?

Comment: yes. The only difference is that in M1 there is no config.php file. There it just takes the alphabetical order of the files from app/etc/modules.